How to configure the max file size for OpenAPI yaml file?
Our Quarkus generated OpenAPI document is large.  When I try to view with Swagger UI I get this error:
'
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.JacksonYAMLParseException: The incoming YAML document exceeds the limit: 3145728 code points.
 at [Source: (InputStreamReader); line: 87426, column: 100]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.nextToken(YAMLParser.java:456)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.nextFieldName(JsonParser.java:1151)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BaseNodeDeserializer._deserializeContainerNoRecursion(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:539)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:100)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer.deserialize(JsonNodeDeserializer.java:25)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:342)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4959)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:3270)
        at io.smallrye.openapi.runtime.io.JacksonJsonIO.fromReader(JacksonJsonIO.java:293)
        ... 76 more
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: The incoming YAML document exceeds the limit: 3145728 code points.
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:317)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:238)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseFlowMappingKey.produce(ParserImpl.java:889)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:162)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.getEvent(ParserImpl.java:172)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.getEvent(YAMLParser.java:590)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLParser.nextToken(YAMLParser.java:450)
        ... 84 more

'
I know that snakeyaml max file size is configurable via:
'
LoaderOptions loadingConfig = new LoaderOptions();
            loadingConfig.setCodePointLimit(maxYamlCodePointSize);
            Yaml yaml = new Yaml(loadingConfig);

'
How can I configure this in a Quarkus application using quarkus-smallrye-openapi?

This can be configured via the property:
mp.openapi.extensions.smallrye.maximumStaticFileSize = 
